# Unable to link to a Rust-compiled library when compiling a C program

Tags: c, gcc, rust, ffi

I have been trying to compile and run a minimal example of calling a Rust function from C. However, I keep getting a linker error:

```
$ gcc -L . test.c -ltest
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWuOBbj.o:test.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `squared'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int squared(int);

int main() {
    printf("5 * 5 = %d", squared(5));
    return 0;
}
```

The Rust code:

```
#![no_std]
#![feature(lang_items)]

extern crate core;

#[lang = "stack_exhausted"] extern fn stack_exhausted() {}
#[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
#[lang = "panic_fmt"] fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop {} }

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn squared(x: isize) -> isize {
    x * x
}
```

I am compiling the Rust code with `rustc --crate-type staticlib -o libtest.a test.rs`

Some details:

- Windows 8 x64
- Rustc version: `1.0.0-nightly (4e4e8cff1 2015-01-24 22:14:14 +0000)`
- GCC version: `4.8.1`
- [Output of DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS](https://gist.github.com/aochagavia/ea441d6225bb5fe8912d)

Comment: This is a nit, but when doing C / Rust interop, you should be particular about the types. I'd use `i32` or `i64` instead of `isize` (which changes depending on 32- or 64-bit). Use the matching type on the C side. You could also use something like `intptr`.

Comment: This is a very common problem for newbies, and is solved by placing the libraries you link with *after* the source/object files, so `$ gcc -L. test.c -ltest`

Comment: Doesn't work :/ (I get the same error)

Comment: @Shepmaster, @aochagavia: You shouldn't use types like `i32` or `isize` when you're dealing with C interop and types like `int` or `short`.  You should use the types in the `libc` crate like `c_int`, which are guaranteed to be the right size on all platforms.

Comment: @DK Is `i32` not guaranteed to be te same width on all platforms?

Comment: @Shepmaster I am on Windows 8 64bit. Dependency Walker throws an error when I open `libtest.a`: "No DOS or PE signature found. This file is not a valid 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module."

Comment: @aochagavia: It is.  But `int` isn't.  `libc::c_int` is guaranteed to be the same size as `int` everywhere.

Comment: Which Rust version? I'm using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (4be79d6ac 2015-01-23 16:08:14 +0000)` and it works with clang and GCC perfectly.

Comment: @hauleth Are you also on windows? I am using rustc 1.0.0-nightly (4e4e8cff1 2015-01-24 22:14:14 +0000) and gcc 4.8.1

Comment: @Shepmaster this is the output of DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS https://gist.github.com/aochagavia/ea441d6225bb5fe8912d. There is a `squared` entry... I am on 64 bit

Comment: woah woah woah... where's your c code for the squared() function?  I only see a squared prototype

Comment: @RobLatham the first line of the question says: "a minimal example of calling a Rust function from C". `squared` is supposed to be coming from Rust code compiled to a library.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have incorporated the relevant info in the question

Comment: I followed your instructions on a Windows 7, 32-bit VM with Rust from 2015-01-14, and was able to correctly link and run the program...

Comment: @aochagavia no I'm on Ubuntu (Linux niuniobook 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Put "-ltest" *after* "test.c".  ld only links in required parts of library archives, and doesn't know squared() is required until it sees the .o file generated from test.c, at which time libtest.a has already been linked earlier when no functions were yet required from it.

Comment: This seems related to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152418/unable-to-link-to-a-rust-compiled-library-when-compiling-a-c-program#comment44676272_28152418). OP [said that didn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152418/unable-to-link-to-a-rust-compiled-library-when-compiling-a-c-program#comment44676386_28152418)

Comment: Oops, I missed that.

OP, try running "nm libtest.a" to verify that libtest.a actually has the squared() function in it,

Comment: This is the output: https://gist.github.com/aochagavia/53891d88988826fba955 (no square function in it)